# Fragment in LinearLayout not appear without layout_weight property

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have two fragments (*MyListFragment*, *MyDetailFragment*) in one activity(*MyActivity*). The first fragment is a list of items, the second one is detail of an item (which is another list, but I think it doesn't matter). The first list fragment is shown when *MyActivity* starts.

*MyListFragment* view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment class="myapp.ActionsList"
              android:id="@+id/actions_list_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*MyDetailFragment* view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:tag="@string/activities_list_tag"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a click handler on *MyListFragment* which calls method in *MyActivity* which opens the *MyDetailFragment*.

```
@Override
public void onActionSelected(MAction action, Integer position){
/**some code...*/
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
                     new MyDetailFragment(mAction,position)).commit();
}
```

### The problem is:

that when I click on any item in *MyListFragment*, the *MyDetailFragment* won't show up (although I know it's lifecycle methods are called properly).

I found out that when I put **android:layout_weight="1"** to fragment definition in *MyListFragment*, it works. **Does anybody know why?**

As I understand the android:layout_weight property, it should play some role only when there are more view in LinearLaoyout, but I have only one.

This is the working layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment class="myapp.ActionsList"
              android:id="@+id/actions_list_fragment"
              **android:layout_weight="1"**
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was doing wrong one thing.

Only fragments loaded programmatically can be replaced. Not fragments defined in xml.

But I didn't know it. Because MyListFragmentView contains fragment in xml definition, so although I called replaced, the method didn't replace actions_list_fragment with new one but put new one after actions_list_fragment. That's why layout_weights made it work - there were two childs in root LinearLayout but I though there is only one.

Comment: I'd like to, but StackOverflow says I can accept own answer in two days. I wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
                 new MyDetailFragment(mAction,position)).commit();
```

You are completely replacing a fragment, so there's only one fragment's view in `fragment_container` at a time. Better make `fragment_container` a `FrameLayout` and set height and width of fragment layout roots to `match_parent`.

Comment: Well, I used match_parent (fill_parent respectively) in all root layout. When I change LinearLayout to FrameLayout, it somehow works (the new fragment overlaps the first one). But still I must be missing something. Why do I see the first fragment when I call "replace" method. And if there is only one fragment's view, why layout_weight must be set?

Comment: @fandasson This issue comes when one of the fragment is embedded in layout xml. If you `add()` first fragment from code at runtime (in `onCreate()`) , then `replace()` will work properly.

Comment: you're right. I already post post it in my answer. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using layout_weight wrong and i don't think u understood it's functionality. In order to function in LinearLayout parrent you must have a weightSum which will be the total weight of the layout. The second thing would be to set childs weight or height 0dp depending on the LinearLayout orientation. Every child of the layout must have a layout_weight and the total sum of the weight to be equal to weightSum. Such that the Layout will be splited automatically depending you're weight.

Comment: I got the way how layout_weight works. What I didn't understand was why putting layout_weights attribute make it work althought it shouldn't (because I expected only one child in root LinearLayout in MyListFragment, but I was wrong in this - check my answer to this question)